# Replace regex submatched fields with extracts from email body

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

First, Here is exactly what I want to do.

1. Open outlook if it isn't already
2. highlite an email from the quickview pane
3. Run VBA code from an icon on the ribbon
4. The code will pick up 3 items from the currently selected email using regular expressions.
5. The 3 items will be used to fill in a form in my drafts folder with a specific subject.
6. The previous items will be used to replace fields in the form that are enclosed in braces `{}` or curly brackets, I've heard them called both.
7. The email will pop up but wait for me to send it.

Now, onto the code I've come up with so far.

```
Public Function GetIDsRegExp()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Dim objRegExp As RegExp
Dim sString As String
Dim sBody As String
Dim objMatch As Match
Dim colMatches As MatchCollection

Set olMail = olApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
'Debug.Print olMail.Body
    sString = olMail.Body

    Set objRegExp = New RegExp

    With objRegExp
        .Pattern = "(?:message|instrument)ID\s+:(\w+)"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
    End With

    If (objRegExp.Test(sString) = True) Then

        'Get the matches.
         Set colMatches = objRegExp.Execute(sString)   ' Execute search.



        For Each objMatch In colMatches   ' Iterate Matches collection.
            Debug.Print objMatch.SubMatches(0)

'      sBody = Replace(Template, "{MessageID}", objMatch.SubMatches(0))
'      sBody = Replace(Template, "{InstrumentID}", objMatch.SubMatches(0))
'      Debug.Print sBody

        Next

    End If

    Template = FindTemplate()
    Debug.Print Replace(Template, "{Date}", Now())

End Function

Function FindTemplate()
        Set objOutlook = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application")
        Set objDrafts = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(16)
        Set objItems = objDrafts.Items

        For Each objDraft In objItems
                If objDraft.Subject = "Environment : Prod International Trade Error" Then
                        FindTemplate = objDraft.Body
                        Exit Function
                End If
        Next
End Function
```

When I debug.print the code, I get exactly what I want. Now, I need to replace fields enclosed by {} in the template with the right submatched extracts. I'm stuck on 5 and 6.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to change from {} to {adress} so you can do a string replace?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

```
String = Replace(title, "something", "{adres}")
```

It should be also possible to compile an entire email from vba so you can bypass the draft folder (that's a step i don't fully get)?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861332.aspx

```
Sub CreateMail() 

 Dim myItem As Object 

 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 

 myItem.Subject = "Mail to myself" 

 myItem.Display 

End Sub
```

Comment: I really just want to have a template file in the drafts folder with the 3 items to replace. I'd prefer to do it with a regex just because I'm just learning them and want to start using them more because of the sheer power they give. I think I'm going to have to break it up into 2 functions. One to find them and another to do the replace. I tried working with the regex replace function but it didn't do what I expected, which is to locate the expected text and replace it with new text as defined in the replace function as seen in this [example](https://blog.udemy.com/vba-regex/)

Comment: Oke I get that, if I have some time today i will look into it, I have an idea I can use this as well. I don't know if i can work with the regex replace function, the link doesn't and I don't know the function in detail. [link] (http://regexr.com/) is always really helpful in tweaking my regexes.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm actually very close. I broke the find in the selected email into a separate function and the replace into another. I haven't had time to work on it today yet. I'll post the code when I get it. Thanks for the regex tester. I use [regex101](http://www.regex101.com)